# whoosh library not importing

Tags: python, import, whoosh

I'm trying to use the whoosh python library.

I added it to my system via pip, and can see it in my python dist-packages folder, which is on the path.

in my code I have:

```
from whoosh.fields import Schema, TEXT

schema = Schema(title=TEXT, content=TEXT)
```

As per the whoosh documentation, but this throws "importerror: no module named fields"

What am I doing wrong?

(I'm running python 2.7)

Comment: did you install it in a virtualenv?

Comment: No, I'm on desktop ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Have you checked for any circular imports?

Comment: Yes, it's the first file in my project I tried adding it to :(